# How to sort a JS Object in this order: letters, numbers, additional characters

Tags: javascript

I have an object with these keys/values and i use something like this to order it:

```
var order = {};
Object.keys(schriften_geladen[schrift_id]["zeichen"]).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  order[key] = schriften_geladen[schrift_id]["zeichen"][key];
});
console.log(order);
```

the result is something like this: 
first all the numbers, second the punctuation marks, third the capital letters, than the lowercase letters and than some special/foreign characters like "ä,é,è…"

```
0: "16"
1: "16"
2: "18"
…
! : "10"
& : "8"
( : "6"
) : "6"
* : "4"
…
A: "20"
B : "14"
C: "15"
…
a : "52"
b : "21"
c : "30"
…
é : "22"
ė : "12"
```

How can i modify the order to have:

```
1: all capital letters
2: all lowercase letters
3: all punctuation marks
4: all special/foreign characters
5: all numbers
```

is this possible?

Comment: you can not order an object, actually. but you could use an array wioth the keys and order that instead.

Comment: why do you need the keys ordered? for pretty-printing/logging? or for further processing?

Comment: @Thomas I: need the order for further processing: the output will be a html-list in the hopefully right order

Comment: @NinaScholz: thanks, but i can store the orderd array in an object, right? Do you have any further information about how to order the array in the required order?

Comment: do you have a complete list of all characters?

Comment: no, where is not something like a complete list of all possible characters.